# Permissions to READ EKS cluster from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, was

I have an EKS cluster and EC2.  I would like to create an instance profile and attach it to the EC2 - this profile should allow ONLY READ access to the EKS cluster.

Will the following policy be apt for this requirement?:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:ListNodegroups",
                "eks:DescribeFargateProfile",
                "eks:ListTagsForResource",
                "eks:ListAddons",
                "eks:DescribeAddon",
                "eks:ListFargateProfiles",
                "eks:DescribeNodegroup",
                "eks:ListUpdates",
                "eks:DescribeUpdate",
                "eks:AccessKubernetesApi",
                "eks:DescribeCluster",
                "eks:ListClusters",
                "eks:DescribeAddonVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "read" access.

If you mean "read" from AWS perspective as in being able to use the AWS CLI to tell you about EKS, yes that would be sufficient to get you started. This will not include any `kubectl` commands.

But if you mean read as in being able to execute `kubectl` commands against the cluster, then you will not be able to achieve that with this.

To implement read access to the cluster itself using `kubectl` commands, your EC2 instance will need a minimum of the following IAM permissions:

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:DescribeCluster",
                "eks:ListClusters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this, your EC2 will be able to execute `eksctl utils write-kubeconfig --cluster=cluster-name` to configure the kubeconfig. This also assumes you have the required components installed on your EC2 to run kubectl.

You also need to set up permissions within your cluster because the IAM permissions alone don't actually grant any visibility within the cluster itself.

The role you assign to your EC2 would need to be added to the `aws-auth` configmap in the `kube-system` namespace. See [Managing users or IAM roles for your cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) from AWS docs for examples.

Unfortunately I don't believe there's a simple out-of-the-box RBAC role you can use that gives you read-only access to the entire cluster. Kubernetes provides four user-facing roles and of them, only the system:masters group has cluster-wide access.

Have a look at Kubernetes [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles) documentation - specifically on user-facing roles.

You will need to design a permission strategy to fit your needs, but you do have the default role `view` that you can start from. The default `view` user-facing role is tied to a ClusterRoleBinding and was designed / intended to be used in a namespace specific capacity.

Permissions and RBAC for Kubernetes is a very deep rabbit-hole.